# Cursed Item Drawback Price Reductions: Do They Stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, stacking, curses

The rules for intentionally crafting cursed items in Pathfinder 1e lists the different curse types and how they modify an item's price.

If a cursed item possesses multiple types of curses, for example, it's uncontrolled or unreliable, -10% to price, and causes ability damage ,-30% to price, do you add the different price reductions together, or do you only apply the highest deduction, regardless of the item's other drawbacks?

Additionally, does the stacking apply to multiple drawbacks and requirements, or only a drawback and a different type of curse, like intermittent functioning?  And finally, if stacking of the price reductions is allowed, does that mean you could theoretically have a cursed item worth 0 gold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The price reduction would stack.

Each of those is it's own type of curse, and thus reduces the price accordingly.

However, you should note that the [cursed item crafting rules](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Crafting%20Cursed%20Items&Category=Cursed%20Items) state:

> Drawbacks and Requirements: **Drawbacks and requirements typically don’t reduce the cost of a cursed item in any way (and might increase it).** Since the crafter of an intentionally cursed item is setting these requirements, it is expected that she does so with a particular agenda, such as choosing a requirement that doesn’t affect her very much but would make the item painful for her enemies to use should they steal it, or choosing a requirement that she wants someone to perform anyway and then offering the item as a gift.
>
> **That said, these curses typically affect the price when selling the cursed items to a merchant.** The price may be reduced by 10% for minor drawbacks or requirements such as minimum skill ranks or the worship of a specific deity; by 30% for harmful or costly drawbacks or requirements such as an alignment change, ability damage, sacrificing wealth, or performing a quest to activate the item; or by 50% for severe drawbacks or requirements such as negative levels that cannot be removed or needing to routinely sacrifice sentient creatures to the item.

So a cursed belt of +2 strength would still cost the same to craft as a normal belt of +2 strength, despite selling to merchants for less.

Note that this doesn't mean a merchant will sell you the item cheaper either, instead they may charge you full price, as it's only reduced when selling to merchants.

Comment: Huh, I would have expected that to read the same as the d20pfsrd page on cursed items, but there's actually some different information at the link you provided.  That additional information is helpful, thanks for linking that!

Comment: Hey willuwontu, since you're previous advice was so helpful, do you have anything to add in regards to my secondary questions?  If you do, I'd really appreciate hearing what you have to say!

Comment: @Gelleck imo, different levels of them would stack but not ones at the same level (e.g. a curse and drawback that both reduce price by 10% wouldn't stack, but one that reduces price by 10% and one that reduces price by 30% would). In that vein, you could have a magic item that's worth 0 gp to merchants (or even that you have to pay them to take it off your hands), but ymmv. Ultimately ask your GM.

Comment: In this case, I'm actually the GM.  I've been working on some fun and odd items for my players to find and I wanted to make sure I was calculating everything out correctly.  Thanks again for the help, willuwontu!